# List duplicates itself after some time

Tags: android

Here is the scenario.

**1)** I have a listview which generates a list of all the songs (which is a fragment)

**2)** Now upon clicking upon any song, a new activity is launched.

**3)** Here is the problem I face,upon coming back from the new activity after **some** time(mind it, it doesn't happen when I come back instantly) I find the list has repeated it self.
And when I click on any item, it doesn'w work.

I have no clue why this happens and what I can do it avoid it.

code :

```
public class F_Songs extends Fragment implements Serializable {

    ListView SngList;

    ArrayList<SongDetails> songdetails = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
    String[] TRACK_COLUMNS;
    Cursor songCursor = null;
    Adapter_ListView ab;
    int index;
    MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.l_songs, null);
        TRACK_COLUMNS = new String[] { MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ALBUM, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.ARTIST,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, };
        String sortOrder = "REPLACE ('<BEGIN>' || " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + ", '<BEGIN>The ', '<BEGIN>')"
                + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
        // MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";
        Cursor songCursor = getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, TRACK_COLUMNS,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION + ">= 10000", null, sortOrder);
        if (songCursor != null) {
            while (songCursor.moveToNext()) {
                SongDetails songs = new SongDetails();
                songs.song = songCursor.getString(8);
                songs.Path = songCursor.getString(2);
                songs.Album = songCursor.getString(0);
                songs.Artist = songCursor.getString(1);
                songdetails.add(songs);
            }
        }
        SngList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(SngList);
        /*
         * String uri = "android.resource://" +
         * this.getActivity().getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.ro; SongDetails
         * songs = new SongDetails(); songs.setPath2( uri) ;
         * songs.setSong("ro"); songdetails.add(songs);
         */
        SngList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView a, View v, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Player.class);
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Data1", songdetails);
                intent.putExtra("Data2", position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ab = new Adapter_ListView(songdetails);
        SngList.setAdapter(ab);

    }
}
```

Comment: you do realize that there is absolutely no element whatsoever to identify your issue in your question, right?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add fragment code and also the `<activity>` tags from your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: we might also need the activity code that creates the fragment. Also, can you explain how you are leaving the app and then returning to it.  It is unclear if you are re-launching it form the app drawer or using recent apps ui.

Comment: In your `onCreateView()` after your `if (songCursor != null) {`, just insert this `songdetails.clear()` and tell me if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find where the problem comes from. My guess will be that it's because of this line

```
ArrayList<SongDetails> songdetails = new ArrayList<SongDetails>();
```

Outside the `onCreateView` method.

Try improve your data managing using MVC pattern and Singleton, like I suggest you in the previous question.